# How to use image() function to plot the data in R

Tags: r

I have a clinical dataset and I would like to plot it using `image()` function to see if I can spot out the different groups within my data.

The structure of this data is a `List of 2`: 56 samples and 5000 gene expressions.

When I use `image(lung)`, all I see a just a plot of orange color and I do not see pattern or any group standing out to me.

Basically, there are four types of clinical conditions in the dataset: Colon cancer (13 samples), smallcell (6 samples), etc.

I wanted to see, for instance, ```smallcell" with 6 samples has its own pattern compared to the rest of the groups/conditions within this dataset.

```
load(url("https://github.com/hughng92/dataset/raw/master/lung.RData"))
rownames(lung)
image(lung)
```

This is all I see:
[image]

I am wondering if I can **combine** the four different plots of these 4 conditions from the data set, it will look different.

Any tip would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking at the image output after rearranging the like types together. I think I now see some group differences in those gene expression profiles. Specifically the "Normal" category has generally fewer red bands although there are a couple where "normal" is red and the others are not. I think it is interesting, and not particularly surprising, that the appears to be less variability within the Normal columns (in the image) than there is within each the tumor types. I have a friend who's a molecular biologist who characterizes tumors as "genetic train wrecks":

```
table( rownames( lung[order(rownames(lung)), ]))

Carcinoid     Colon    Normal SmallCell 
       20        13        17         6
```

## ------------------

```
 image( lung[order(rownames(lung)), ])
```

[image]

This would give a better indication of the boundaries of the type grouping:

```
image( lung[order(rownames(lung)), ], xaxt="n")
axis(1, at=(cumsum( table( rownames( lung[order(rownames(lung)), ])))-1)/56 ,
        labels=names(table( rownames( lung[order(rownames(lung)), ]))),las=2)
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the response. I find it hard to work with R data structure.

Comment: This solution is very similar to Matlab or GLIM syntax.